# Keyboard overflows even with resizeToAvoidBottomInset false or SingleChildScrollView

Tags: flutter, dart

When selecting a textfield and the keyboard pops up, I get the overflowed message and notice that the container that has my background moves as well, even using `resizeToAvoidBottomInset`. I also tried `SingleChildScrollView` which resulted in a constraint error. My guess is my background isn't where it should be, but I'm not sure where I should put it or if my mistake lies somewhere else, the `WillPopScope()` made the `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` stop working but if that's the case, how do I lock the back button?

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:studentcompanion/constants/colors.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:studentcompanion/core/myDB.dart';
import 'package:studentcompanion/screens/home/Menu.dart';
import '../../core/session.dart';
import '../profile/student.dart';

class Login extends StatelessWidget {
  Login({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final _emailController = TextEditingController();
  final _passwordController = TextEditingController();

  Future<bool> _onWillPop() async {
    return false; 
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: _onWillPop,
      child: Scaffold(
          resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
          body: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                      begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                      end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                      colors: [
                    ColorConstant.bluegray200,
                    ColorConstant.pink100
                  ])),
              child: SizedBox(
                  child: Column(
                children: [
                  Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 60),
                      child: Image.asset('assets/images/Icon.png')),
                  const Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                      child: Text(
                        '¡Bienvenido(a)!',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 35,
                            fontFamily: 'Jost',
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      )),
                  const SizedBox(height: 30),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25.0),
                    child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.grey[100],
                            border: Border.all(color: Colors.white),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12)),
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
                          child: TextField(
                            controller: _emailController,
                            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                border: InputBorder.none, hintText: 'Email'),
                          ),
                        )),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 10),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25.0),
                    child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.grey[100],
                            border: Border.all(color: Colors.white),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12)),
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
                          child: TextField(
                            controller: _passwordController,
                            obscureText: true,
                            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                border: InputBorder.none,
                                hintText: 'Contraseña'),
                          ),
                        )),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 40),
                      child: InkWell(
                        child: Container(
                            height: 50,
                            width: 150,
                            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                boxShadow: [
                                  BoxShadow(
                                    color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2),
                                    spreadRadius: 3,
                                    blurRadius: 7,
                                    offset: const Offset(0, 5),
                                  )
                                ]),
                            child: const Center(
                                child: Text('Ingresar',
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.black,
                                        fontSize: 20,
                                        fontFamily: 'Jost',
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400)))),
                        onTap: () {
                          login(context);
                        },
                      )),
                  const Spacer(),
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    child: Image.asset('assets/images/Waves.png',
                        width: double.infinity, fit: BoxFit.cover),
                  )
                ],
              )))),
    );
  }
```

[image]

Thank you in advance!

Tried using resizeToAvoidBottomInset = false and  SingleChildScrollView which resulted in no differences or constraint errors.

Comment: Were did you use the _SingleChildScrollView_ while testing (as parent of the first _Container_ or of the _Column_) ?

Comment: @fsbelinda on both, and both throw the constraint error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up getting rid of the Container and just having a Column inside my Scaffold, then used **SingleChildScrollView** which overrides the spacing of the column, so I wrapped the column inside a  **ConstrainedBox** with `maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height` and it ended up working how I wanted.

Comment: can share your snippet codes @Claudia Provoste ?